# add unique entry on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, uniqueidentifier, rails-activerecord

i am trying to add a unique entry on click so that a user can accept an event they have been invited to. the user should only be able to click this link once. at present i have the following code which seems to be adding the entry, though i dont think its the best practice, plus the unique id doesn't seem to be working too well

haml

```
             %li= link_to 'Add', availabilities_path(:availability => {:team_id => @event.team_id, :user_id => user, :event_id => @event.id, :unique_id => availability_unique_id(user,@event) }), :remote => true, :method => :post, :class => 'button tiny success'
```

model

```
validates :unique_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

unique method

```
def availability_unique_id(player,schedule)
    Base64.encode64("#{player.to_s}_#{schedule.id.to_s}_#{schedule.team.id.to_s}")
  end
```

as you can see from the query below the unique value isn't being looked out

```
select * from availabilities where user_id = 41;
 id | available | user_id | team_id | event_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         |            unique_id             | comment 
----+-----------+---------+---------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+---------
 61 |           |      41 |         |          | 2012-11-04 13:48:22.794214 | 2012-11-04 13:48:22.794214 | NDFfNDNfMQ==                    +| 
    |           |         |         |          |                            |                            |                                  | 
 84 |           |      41 |       1 |       75 | 2013-02-09 14:03:29.792374 | 2013-02-09 14:03:29.792374 | IzxVc2VyOjB4YWY3NTMxND5fNzVfMQ==+| 
    |           |         |         |          |                            |                            |                                  | 
 85 |           |      41 |       1 |       75 | 2013-02-09 14:06:04.131862 | 2013-02-09 14:06:04.131862 | IzxVc2VyOjB4YjJhODBiOD5fNzVfMQ==+| 
    |           |         |         |          |                            |                            |                                  | 
 87 |           |      41 |       1 |       75 | 2013-02-09 14:07:31.77788  | 2013-02-09 14:07:31.77788  | IzxVc2VyOjB4YjBhYjdiMD5fNzVfMQ==+| 
    |           |         |         |          |                            |                            |                                  |
```

Comment: hi Paul, i don't get what you mean. the table shows unique unique_ids if you look closely

Comment: hi yes it shows them, but they arent unique, i was thinking by using uniqueness in my model that it would only allow that value to be used once, is that not the case? thanks

Comment: sorry i see that they are unique, what im trying to achieve than is that a user, from an event can only appear once in the table, what would be the best method of achieving this

Comment: user should only appear once on the table per event id? try `validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :event_id }`

Comment: yup only once, i thought i would have to create my only unique_id which doesnt appear to be very unique

Comment: nope no need for a unique_id. i've added an answer from the comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments.  the validation below makes sure that you have a unique `user_id` for each `event_id`.  you can add multiple scopes if needed.

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :event_id }
```

Comment: with how im doing the link, is there a better way to achieve the same results just so the params aren't viewable from the path?

Comment: yes, you can use `button_to` which creates a form or manually create a form with the params as hidden values.

Comment: jvnill, with how the button is working, could this be better achieved by calling a method so i dont have so much login within the view?